# Java - AWT: Making objects point to other objects

Tags: java, object, awt

I am a begginer java programmer for AWT, and I'm wondering how I make `Enemy()` point to `Player()`. Here is my code so far:

Player.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Player extends GameObject {
    public Player(int x, int y, Color color) {
       super(x, y, color);
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
    }   
}
```

Enemy.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Enemy extends GameObject {
    public Enemy(int x, int y, Color color) {
        super(x, y, color);
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
    }   
}
```

So how can I begin moving `Enemy()` towards `Player()` so the game actually works?

Comment: Where are velX and velY declared?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to a GameObject somehow. You're missing that in your design. Somewhere, in these two classes, or another class, you should be keeping track of a reference to a GameObject variable that you can then just set to be the enemy player. There's no way to arbitrarily make one class into another.